# How Would I write a String.Format Extension Method?

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods

I use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) in my C# code probably more than anything aside from the `if` statement.

```
string ask = String.Format("Continue using [{0}]?", value);
```

I just got to thinking of how often I use it.

Next, I got to thinking of how great it would be to create an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) for it.

```
ask.Format("Continue using [{0}]?", value);
```

So, I got to looking at [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx), and it has many overloads because there are many ways that it could be called.

- [Format(String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx)
- [Format(String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx)
- [Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx)
- [Format(String, Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf3d0ccc.aspx)
- [Format(String, Object, Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9t40k6d.aspx)

Hmmm... That complicates things.

### Would there be a simple way of writing an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) that simply builds on the overloads already existing in the `System.String` namespace?

Here is what I would like to see:

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static String Format(this String str, String formatText, /* What goes here? */)
  {
    return str.Format(formatText, /* Magic */);
  }
}
```

I suppose I **could** write an overload to match each of the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) overloads, but that may not be necessary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
ask.Format("Continue using [{0}]?", value);
```

is not how I would use it. Here's what I would do:

```
var ask = "Continue using [{0}]?".FormatWith(value);
```

And here's my extension method:

```
public static string FormatWith(this string value, params object[] args)
{
    return String.Format(value, args);
}
```

Comment: Mike, I edited your code a bit to include the `formatText` string. Otherwise, this worked just as I wanted.

Comment: where should i put that method

Comment: In a static class anywhere in your project/solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You want to modify the calling string. You can't do that. Strings in .Net do not change (they are immutable), and so you would still have to return a new string. The closest you can get from C# is code like this:

```
string ask = $"Continue using [{value}]?";
```

It would be possible to modify your original string if you could pass the extension object by reference. Unfortunately, C# does not support this.

What's interesting is that the IL *does* support it, and you could write the method you wanted using VB.Net:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Shared Sub Format(ByRef str As String, ByVal formatText As String, ByVal ParamArray args As Object())
    str = String.Format(formatText, args);
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, even if you stuff this in a VB.Net class library project, you wouldn't be able to call it from C#, because C# requires you to use the `ref` keyword at the call site when calling functions with parameters by reference, and there is no syntax for this with an extension method.

For a work-around that doesn't exactly match your desired syntax, but will still give you something pretty nice, see [Mike Cole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16612342/3043).

Answer (score 1):

You were close, missing only the `params object[] args` parameter:

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static String Format(this String str, 
                              String formatText, 
                              params object[] args)
  {
    return str.Format(formatText, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this infinitely recursive?

Comment: It is, but I quickly understood what he meant. He probably just went with my untested sample code, which was already infinitely recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Use string interpolation (in C# 6.0 and VS 2015+). Your code would look like this:

```
var ask = $"Continue using [{value}]?";
```

I had been using either String.Format or string concatenation until I discovered string interpolation and now I'm hooked.

One potential downside to this is that you can't factor out your format strings to constants or resources. Have a look here for more details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

This article goes into more details and includes some other nice gems. Definitley worth a read:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx

Comment: To be fair, we've only been able to do this in C# since VS 2015, so there is a *lot* of old code out there that doesn't use it.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Good point. This probably won't be so useful for supporting/refactoring old codebases. But it's great for newer projects.